# Resume a ml-agents training after changing hyperparameters and adding new observation vectors

Tags: tensorflow, unity-game-engine, resume

I am working on training an agents thanks to ml-agents with Unity. When I changed the number of stacked vector, the observation vectors and  the hyperparameters I can not resume the training from the last training because tensorflow tells me there is a problem for the lhs rhs shape that are not the same.

I would like to be able to change the agent scripts and config scripts and resume the training with this new parameters not to loose the past progress the agent made...Because for the moment I must restart a new training or not change the number of observations vectors etc.

How to do so ?

Thank you very much.

EDIT : Here an example of what I want to test and what errors I got with RollerBall ML-agents tutorial. See here https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Learning-Environment-Create-New.md

GOAL : I want to see the impact of the observations vector choice on the agent's training.

1. I ran a learning with the basic script for the agent given in the tutorial. Here it is :

   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;
   using Unity.MLAgents;
   using Unity.MLAgents.Sensors;

   public class RollerAgent : Agent
   {
   Rigidbody rBody;
   void Start()
   {
   rBody = GetComponent();
   }

   ```
    public Transform Target;
    public override void OnEpisodeBegin()
    {
        if (this.transform.localPosition.y < 0)
        {
            // If the Agent fell, zero its momentum
            this.rBody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
            this.rBody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            this.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0);
        }

        // Move the target to a new spot
        Target.localPosition = new Vector3(Random.value * 8 - 4,
                                           0.5f,
                                           Random.value * 8 - 4);
    }
    public override void CollectObservations(VectorSensor sensor)
    {
        // Target and Agent positions
        sensor.AddObservation(Target.localPosition);
        sensor.AddObservation(this.transform.localPosition);

        // Agent velocity
        sensor.AddObservation(rBody.velocity.x);
        sensor.AddObservation(rBody.velocity.z);
    }
    public float speed = 10;

    public override void OnActionReceived(float[] vectorAction)
    {
        // Actions, size = 2
        Vector3 controlSignal = Vector3.zero;
        controlSignal.x = vectorAction[0];
        controlSignal.z = vectorAction[1];
        rBody.AddForce(controlSignal * speed);

        // Rewards
        float distanceToTarget = Vector3.Distance(this.transform.localPosition, Target.localPosition);

        // Reached target
        if (distanceToTarget < 1.42f)
        {
            SetReward(1.0f);
            EndEpisode();
        }

        // Fell off platform
        if (this.transform.localPosition.y < 0)
        {
            EndEpisode();
        }
    }
    public override void Heuristic(float[] actionsOut)
    {
        actionsOut[0] = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        actionsOut[1] = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    }
    }
   ```
2. I stopped the training before the agent hit the benchmark.
3. I suppressed the observation vectors concerning the velocity observation of the agent and adjusted the number of observation vector in unity from 8 to 6. Here is the new code :

   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;
   using Unity.MLAgents;
   using Unity.MLAgents.Sensors;

   public class RollerAgent : Agent
   {
   Rigidbody rBody;
   void Start()
   {
   rBody = GetComponent();
   }

   ```
    public Transform Target;
    public override void OnEpisodeBegin()
    {
        if (this.transform.localPosition.y < 0)
        {
            // If the Agent fell, zero its momentum
            this.rBody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
            this.rBody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            this.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0);
        }

        // Move the target to a new spot
        Target.localPosition = new Vector3(Random.value * 8 - 4,
                                           0.5f,
                                           Random.value * 8 - 4);
    }
    public override void CollectObservations(VectorSensor sensor)
    {
        // Target and Agent positions
        sensor.AddObservation(Target.localPosition);
        sensor.AddObservation(this.transform.localPosition);

        // Agent velocity
        //sensor.AddObservation(rBody.velocity.x);
        //sensor.AddObservation(rBody.velocity.z);
    }
    public float speed = 10;

    public override void OnActionReceived(float[] vectorAction)
    {
        // Actions, size = 2
        Vector3 controlSignal = Vector3.zero;
        controlSignal.x = vectorAction[0];
        controlSignal.z = vectorAction[1];
        rBody.AddForce(controlSignal * speed);

        // Rewards
        float distanceToTarget = Vector3.Distance(this.transform.localPosition, Target.localPosition);

        // Reached target
        if (distanceToTarget < 1.42f)
        {
            SetReward(1.0f);
            EndEpisode();
        }

        // Fell off platform
        if (this.transform.localPosition.y < 0)
        {
            EndEpisode();
        }
    }
    public override void Heuristic(float[] actionsOut)
    {
        actionsOut[0] = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        actionsOut[1] = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    }
    }
   ```
4. I ran again with the same ID and I RESUMED the training so as to keep the advancement made during the last training. But when I pressed the play button on the Unity editor I got this error :

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:
> Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a
> mismatch between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint.
> Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on
> the checkpoint. Original error:
>
> Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [6,128]
> rhs shape= [8,128]
> [[node save_1/Assign_26 (defined at c:\users\jeann\anaconda3\envs\ml-agents-1.0.2\lib\site-packages\mlagents\trainers\policy\tf_policy.py:115)
> ]]
>
> Errors may have originated from an input operation.

5. I know that it makes non-sense to use the advancement of the last training whereas I use a new brain configuration for the agent, but in the project I am currently working on, I need to keep the improvement made by the agent before even if we change the observation vectors. Is there a way to do so or it is impossible ?

Thank you :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What code do you currently have? Please provide as much relevant detail as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited the questions by adding every steps. I hope you can help me now.